# My reputation is shrinking with no reasons

Tags: discussion, reputation

I have been busy with other things in my life lately, so I haven't been active on MSE for the last couple of days. First my reputation decreased by 2 points few days ago, and today when I checked my profile again my reputation had decreased by another 8 points. I checked the reputation tab and it didn't show any downvotes or changes in my reputation. How is that possible?

Answer (score 7):

The loss of reputation appears to be due to the (in this case automatic) deletion of questions on math.SE.

When a question (or any post, really) is deleted, all up- and down-votes associated with that post (and all associated changes in reputation) are also removed.  Also, reputation earned by editing such posts are removed.

Comment: Yes, but such changes are shown in the reputation tab. Moreover, if an answer is removed then I must lose 10 points, how is it possible that once I lose 2 points then later I lose 6 points?

Comment: @some1.new4u: Regarding your first point, I am not certain exactly what you see in your reputation tab, but I suspect that you do not see events associated with deleted posts (or perhaps they are mysteriously described).  If you go to your reputation tab listed by "time" do you see any specific events for the following two UTC times `2013-09-28 03:00:20Z` and `2013-09-30 03:00:15Z`?  If so, how are they described?

Comment: Regarding your second point, note that if a question you ask received two upvotes and two downvotes, this results in a net gain of 6 reputation points.  If that question is later deleted this net gain of 6 reputation points is reversed.

Comment: Incidentally, this is behavior on the part of the software that I find incomprehensible: if I invest my time answering a question, and others judge it worthy of upvotes, why do I then lose that reputation when the OP decides to vanish and/or delete his questions?

Comment: @ArthurFischer: Yes, you are right. Some of my posts had been deleted. I always have the option 'show removed posts' on, but apparently this time it was unchecked.

Comment: @user7530: While your average user deletion can cause some drop in reputation, when "highly active" users are deleted [their votes are preserved](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/156520/214632).  (I do not know what counts as highly active.) There are also limits when a user can delete their own questions (no positively scored answers, for one). In this case it was the Community User doing some cleaning up based on its algorithm, which, if it acts incorrectly, is based on the math.SE community not valuing posts as it should.

Comment: @some1.new4u: I'm glad it's been clarified.  I totally forget what regular users can see in their user profiles, and it sometimes drives me mad trying to figure out what is likely to be shown.  I might make a feature-request about this on MSO.

Comment: @ArthurFischer: I guess there is such a feature. When you hover your mouse over your name in the main page and the box that shows your reputation, vote cats, and etc somewhere inside the box it has 'privileges'. That shows what people can see depending on their reputation.